# Binding to UI with KnockoutJS with Computed Functions

Tags: knockout.js

I have this heirarchy of ViewModels

```
Dashboard
 - Layout
   - Columns[]
```

I also have the concept of Widgets that have structure like this

```
WidgetInstance[]
  WidgetInstance
  - InstanceId [integer]
  - Layout
    - Column [integer]
    - Order [integer]
```

Essentially these widgets will all be bound to the `Column[]` array value to which they belong... So imagine a trello-style interface

[image]

I would like to be able to change either then `WidgetInstance.Layout.Order` or `WidgetInstance.Layout.Column`, that the UI automatically updates.  So far I haven't found anything on how to do this...

Here are my questions...

1) Does the WidgetInstance[] belong on the `Dashboard` or does each `Column` need to hold it's own array of `WidgetInstances` for this to work??

2) How would a `data-binding=foreach` look on the `WidgetInstance` list in each case?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable.

The last example, looks like what you are looking for